# Creating a user actions stream in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a stream of actions in my rails App. Here are the helper methods I use to generate a list of likes a user received, and a list of stories a user's friend wrote.

Later, I simply combine these into one array to display in a view. But, I want to sort my final array, by date, but when I use `.map` in the earlier methods, I can't figure out how to get a date object in there that I can sort by.

```
def get_stream(current_user)
    stories = get_friends_stories(current_user)
    likes = get_likes(current_user)
    stream = [stories, likes]
    stream.flatten
  end

def get_likes(user)
    stories = get_stories(user)
    likes = Like.find_all_by_story_id(stories)
    hash = likes.map {|like| "#{like.user.display_name} liked your story #{like.story.title}" }
  end

  def get_friends_stories(user)
    friends = get_friends(user)
    friend_ids = friends.map {|f| f.friend_id }
    stories = Story.find_all_by_user_id(friend_ids)
    hash = stories.map {|story| "#{story.user.display_name} wrote a story called #{story.title}" } 
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple change seems to work:

```
def get_stream(current_user)
    stories = get_friends_stories(current_user)
    likes = get_likes(current_user).sort_by {|l| l.created_at }
    streams = stories + likes
    streams.sort_by(&:created_at)
  end
```